Cannot remove file from Azure Web App on Linux
I have a couple of WordPress websites hosted in Azure with Web App on Linux. I tried to make some update to plugins and when the update get to AIOSEO Redirects, the update crashed because it could not remove the main file of the plugin aioseo-redirects.php .
I tried the command
mv aioseo-redirects.php aioseo-redirects.php.php

... and it returned ...
mv: cannot stat 'aioseo-redirects.php': No such file or directory

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks,
Ciprian

Please check and confirm where you are trying to run the command, file is available in same directory

I have deployed a python app on Linux.
To run command,  SSH into app
- Go to Development tools -> SSH -> Go.


**Note :**all the deployed app files will be avalaible in home\site\wwwroot path.
you can check all files by opening kudu console(SCM url) https://<appname>.scm..azurewebsites.net/newui

First check, if the file is available in the directory where you are trying to run command for the file.

I am running command in directory home\site\wwwroot

To rename file or to move file use mv command:
rename:
mv <old_file_name> <new_file_name>
mv oldfile.txt newfile.txt   #my command

move file:
mv <file_name> path/to/file
eg. mv oldfile.txt home/site #example

To remove/delete file rm command is used
remove file:
rm <file_name>
rm newfile.txt  #my command

OUTPUT


Thank you Vivek. I have already tried that. I supposed the file was locked by some other process. Strange is when I mv the file it returns no error, when I ls it returns the filename. If I rm it says the file does not exist. I tried using FTP and says Access denied. If I search through the processes there is no possible related process. I stopped the app and tried again... nothing. I tried also with stopping just Nginx ... nothing. Using SSH I am root so I should be able to remove the file. Still, can't . Eventually I restored the app in a separate slot and made a swap.

@Ciprian AFAIK sudo doesnot work in linux web app. you can also delete the file directly using scm url. go to scm  url using newui  route at end. then file manager, find your file click on x to delete.
